# Removing Characters of a String

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write a code that asks the user to enter a string and takes of all characters except the alphabetical.

Now i did it myself and it doesn't seem to work properly. I'm new to strings so i'm trying to understand and master strings. I tried to use gdb on mac but i don't have all the functions to understand this. 
Could you please help?

What the code must do: User inputs (for example): `h**#el(l)o&^w`

and the output is `hello.`

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int i;
   int seen = 0;

   printf("Enter String: ");
   scanf("%s", string);

   for (i=0; string[i]!='\0'; i++)
   {
       if (((string[i]<='a' || string[i]>'z')&&(string[i]<='A' || string[i]>'Z')) ||string[i]!='\0')
       {
           seen = 1;
       }
       else
           seen = 0;
   }
   if (seen==0)
   {
       printf("%s", string);
   }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what kind of output you're getting you were not expecting.. i.e. what are the problems?

Comment: wee the program skips my statement and shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

well, your code has a couple of important problems:

- you're not checking boundaries when iterating… what if I type in a 101 characters string? and a 4242 characters string?
- next problem, is that `scanf("%s", …)` [is considered dangerous, for the same reasons](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

so basically, what you'd want is to use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

But why not just get the input character by character, and build a string that has only the chars you want? It's simpler and flexible!

basically:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char* string[100];
    int i=0;

    printf("Enter your string: ");

    do {
        // getting a character
        char c = getchar();
        // if the character is alpha
        if (isalpha(c) != 0)
            // we place the character to the current position and then increment the index
            string[i++] = c;
        // otherwise if c is a carriage return
        else if (c == '\r') {
            c = getchar(); // get rid of \n
            // we end the string
            string[i] = '\0'
        }else if (c == '\n')
            // we end the string
            string[i] = '\0';
    // while c is not a carriage return or i is not out of boundaries
    } while (c != '\n' || i < 100);
    // if we've got to the boundary, replace last character with end of string
    if (i == 100)
        string[i] = '\0';
    // print out!
    printf("Here's your stripped string: %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

I did not run it on my computer because it's getting late, so my apologies in case of mistakes.

Addendum:

> wee the program skips my statement and shuts down

that's because your condition is inversed, and remove the `\0` condition, as it will always happen with the `scanf()` that always append `\0` to the string to end it. Try exchanging `seen = 1` and `seen = 0` or try using the following condition:

```
   if ((string[i]>='a' && string[i]<='z')||(string[i]>='A' && string[i]<='Z')))
        seen = 1;
   else
        seen = 0;
```

or simply, use `ctypes`'s `isalpha()` function, like in our two examples!

Comment: `fgets` might be a better option if you wanted to read several values.  For a single string, I don't think it offers any greater protection from buffer overflow than `scanf("%99s", string)`.

Comment: @zmo thank you for your effort really and from what i see it's also a good idea but i'm mainly trying to understand and trying to do complicated things

Comment: it's good to understand what's wrong when it does not work. But always remember that the less line of code you write and the less complicated it is, the less bugs you'll have… and the easier it will be to reread your code afterwards!

Comment: *"you're not checking boundaries when iterating"* - He's checking bounds while iterating by looking for the null terminator, which is fine.  He should however be using `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

No part(remove the extra characters) to change the string in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *filter(char *string, int (*test)(int)) {
    char *from, *to;
    for(to = from = string;*from;++from){
        if(test(*from))
            *to++ = *from;
    }
    *to = '\0';
    return string;
}

int main(){
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter String: ");
    scanf("%99s", string);
    printf("%s\n", filter(string, isalpha));

    return 0;
}
```