# Reading a string and keep only the letters

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want the user to enter a string, and then keep only the letters. My problem is  in the Function str in the second while loop it nevers copy the letter to the other string.It doesn't even print the j ! I really don't know why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void str(char *s)
{
  int i=0,j=0;
  int sum=0;

  char *outstr;
  while(s[i]!='\0')
     {
       if(s[i]>='a'&&s[i]<='z'||s[i]>='A'&&s[i]<='Z')
        sum++;
      i++;
     }
   i=0;
   outstr=(char*)malloc(sum*sizeof(char));
   while(s[i]!='\0')
    {
      if(s[i]>='a'&&s[i]<='z'||s[i]>='A'&&s[i]<='Z')
         {
            strcpy(outstr[j],s[i]);
            j++;
            printf("\nj=%d",j);
         }

        printf("\ni=%d",i);
        i++;

    }


    printf("%s",outstr);
}

int main()
  {
     char s[650];
     int n;
     gets(s);
     str(s);

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: and avoid using `gets()`, because if you enter 651 characters, then all you'll get is a buffer overflow and an *undefined behaviour*. And as much as you don't need `strcpy()` in your code, when you need it, prefer to use his little brother `strncpy()` which bounds the copied length.

Comment: I know about gets, but i wanted something quick for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21445562/971127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need the strcpy function:

```
strcpy(outstr[j],s[i]);
```

but

```
outstr[j] = s[i];
```

is enough. And also change

```
s[i]>='a'&&s[i]<='z'||s[i]>='A'&&s[i]<='Z'
```

with:

```
(s[i]>='a' && s[i]<='z') || (s[i]>='A' && s[i]<='Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use standard c library routines wherever possible.  For example, you may use the function 
 **isalpha**   to check if a character is a letter.